# animating based on audio iOS

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, avaudioplayer, uianimation

I want the animation to be done based on the audio that will be played?Is this possible to do?
Basically I have a pulse animation that need to be done based on the audio?How can I do this.Hope got my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Detailed implementation of audio capture and processing is available in AudioGraph (https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph). The same demo contains a very basic example of animating based on audio (just displaying a level meter using progress bar controls).

For better animations, you can use OpenGL ES together with the code above. I have done this in one of my projects.

Comment: Apple's AurioTouch example shows how to do animation using microphone input. This can be used as a starting point, if you are less familiar with OpenGL ES.